# office vsto add in not loading on release

Tags: c#, vsto

I have an office add-in (vsto) that has been working fine for ages.
It launches perfectly, runs nicely no problem, but this is only when debugging from visual studio.

If I now take the files from my bin\debug and move it to another folder, then I register the released version

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPlugin\MyVSTO.dll"
```

it registers correctly, but will not load in office. 
I have tried retricking the registry setting "LoadBehavior" setting it back to 3, but no luck.

office keeps complaining about my add in with the error

```
"Not loaded. A runtime error occured during loading of a com add in"
```

So it seems like it is dying when trying to launch. I though there was a missing dll or something, but no such luck, every library i need is in the folder.
This is the exact same machine so shouldnt be a dot net issue

fyi
This is done in C# 4.0 using netOffice

Comment: Any relevant errors in the Windows event viewer?

Comment: Does the add in itself depend on any COM dlls? Or is this all on the same machine?

Comment: this is on the same machine, and no other com dlls

Comment: It's kind of a long shot but you could try using fuslogvw to see if that tells you anything about why the load is failing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can not install an Excel add-in using REGASM because it does not setup all required information; you need to deploy your add-in as per [MSDN office deployment guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.ASPX), you have two choices:

- Click once
- Windows installer

Note: VS actually installs the Add-in for you by setting the right information In Excel and the registry, so that you do not need to deploy the add-in manually for every new build.

Comment: I do use an installer.  It calls regasm under the hood. For testing purposes i call regasm to skip the middle man. But none of that is really pertinent to this question.

Comment: Is your installer following the MSDN deployment guidelines for Windows installer? All steps must be included otherwise it will not work.